# Java-How do I call a class with a string?

Tags: java, string, class, bluej

I am a beginner programmer and this is my first question on this forum.

I am writing a simple text adventure game using BlueJ as a compiler, and I am on a Mac. The problem I ran into is that I would like to make my code more self automated, but I cannot call a class with a string. The reason I want call the class and not have it all in an if function is so that I may incorporate more methods.

Here is how it will run currently:

```
public class textadventure {
public method(String room){
if(room==street){street.enterRoom();}
}
}
public class street{
public enterRoom(){
//do stuff and call other methods
}
}
```

The if statement tests for every class/room I create. What I would like the code to do is automatically make the string room into a class name that can be called. So it may act like so:

```
Public method(string room){
Class Room = room;
Room.enterRoom();
}
```

I have already looked into using Class.forName, but all the examples were too general for me to understand how to use the function. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if there is any other necessary information (such as more example code) I am happy to provide it.

-Sebastien

Here is the full code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Player extends JApplet{
public String textOnScreen;

public void start(){
room("street1");
}

public void room(String room){
    if(room=="street1"){
    textOnScreen=street1.enterRoom();
    repaint();
    }
    if(room=="street2"){
    textOnScreen=street2.enterRoom();
    repaint();
    }
}
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawString(textOnScreen,5,15);
}
}

public abstract class street1
{
private static String textToScreen;
public static String enterRoom(){
    textToScreen = "You are on a street running from North to South.";
    return textToScreen;
}
}

public abstract class street2
{
private static String textToScreen;
public static String enterRoom(){
    textToScreen = "You are on another street.";
    return textToScreen;
}
}
```

Comment: You have a little thing dangling there underneath you...

Comment: There are much better ways to do this.  This approach you're describing is a huge code smell.  (Egads, "stringly typed" code.)

Comment: If Java, `Public` should be lowercase, `string` should be titlecase. `textadventure` should, by convention if not by grammar, also be titlecase.

Comment: when comparing two strings in java u have to use .equals method

Comment: And it doesn't make a lot of sense to name a method "method". If you take a break from programming for a while and come back to rework your code, you will find names like "method" quite confusing and uninforming.

Comment: Indentation is your friend, the same is true for coding guidelines, if you want other people to read your code.

Answer (score 3):

Seeing as you are rather new to programming, I would recommend starting with some programs that are simpler than a full-fledged adventure game.  You still haven't fully grasped some of the fundamentals of the Java syntax.  Take, for example, the HelloWorld program:

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String output = "Hello World!"
    System.out.println(output);
  }   
}
```

Notice that `public` is lowercased.  `Public` with a capital `P` is not the same as `public`.

Also notice that the `String` class has a capital `S`.*  Again, capitalization matters, so `string` is not the same as `String`.

In addition, note that I didn't have to use `String string = new String("string")`.  You can use `String string = "string"`.  This syntax runs faster and is easier to read.

When testing for string equality, you need to use `String.equals` instead of `==`.  This is because `a == b` checks for object equality (i.e. `a` and `b` occupy the same spot in memory)  and `stringOne.equals(stringTwo)` checks to see if `stringOne` has the same characters in the same order as `stringTwo` regardless of where they are in memory.

Now, as for your question, I would recommend using either an `Enum` or a `Map` to keep track of which object to use.

For example:

```
public class Tester {

  public enum Location {

    ROOM_A("Room A", "You are going into Room A"),
    ROOM_B("Room B", "You are going into Room B"),
    OUTSIDE("Outside", "You are going outside");
    private final String name;
    private final String actionText;

    private Location(String name, String actionText) {
      this.name = name;
      this.actionText = actionText;
    }

    public String getActionText() {
      return this.actionText;
    }   

    public String getName() {
      return this.name;
    }   

    public static Location findByName(String name) {
      name = name.toUpperCase().replaceAll("\\s+", "_");
      try {
        return Enum.valueOf(Location.class, name);
      } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return null;
      }   
    }   
  }


  private Location currentLocation;

  public void changeLocation(String locationName) {
    Location location = Location.findByName(locationName);
    if (location == null) {
      System.out.println("Unknown room: " + locationName);
    } else if (currentLocation != null && currentLocation.equals(location)) {
      System.out.println("Already in room " + location.getName());
    } else {
      System.out.println(location.getActionText());
      currentLocation = location;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Tester tester = new Tester();
    tester.changeLocation("room a");
    tester.changeLocation("room b");
    tester.changeLocation("room c");
    tester.changeLocation("room b");
    tester.changeLocation("outside");
  }
}
```

---

*This is the standard way of formating Java code.  Class names are `PascalCased` while variable names are `camelCased`.

Comment: I get it: I'll fix my "grammatical" errors. I was on an ipad when I first posted this, thats why it turned out like that. Otherwise thanks for the advise on the new String() method. I wasn't sure about that, and since the code worked I didn't want to change anything.

Comment: @Sebastien See my edits for an example of how to use `Enum` to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
String className=getClassName();//Get class name from user here
String fnName=getMethodName();//Get function name from user here

Class params[] = {};
Object paramsObj[] = {};

Class thisClass = Class.forName(className);// get the Class

Object inst = thisClass.newInstance();// get an instance
// get the method
Method fn = thisClass.getDeclaredMethod(fnName, params);
// call the method
fn.invoke(inst, paramsObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

The comments below your question are true - your code is very rough.

Anyway, if you have a method like

```
public void doSomething(String str) {
  if (str.equals("whatever")) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Then call it like

```
doSomething("whatever");
```

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Would my answer be more helpful? I would expect it would be at least a bit helpful...

Comment: Sorry meant to ask if posting the full code would be more help.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, many classes have attributes, and you can and will often have multiple instances from the same class.

How would you identify which is which by name?

For example

```
class Room {
    List<Monster> monsters = new ArrayList <Monster> ();
    public Room (int monstercount) {
         for (int i = 0; i < monstercount; ++i)
            monsters.add (new Monster ());
    }
    // ...
}
```

Monsters can have attributes, and if one of them is dead, you can identify it more easily if you don't handle everything in Strings.